# writing new lines in a file in perl

Tags: regex, perl, file-io, newline

I have a directory where I'm editing XML files and converting them into regular text files where - IF there are more than one lines with numbers, then they must be saved in the new files on separate new lines.

For example, if the XML file looks like this:

```
<![CDATA[335 248 450 305
32 251 188 319
472 245 574 290
]]>
```

Then I want the converted file to look like this:

```
Bounding box for object 1 "PAScar" (Xmin, Ymin) - (Xmax, Ymax) : (335, 248) - (450, 305)
Bounding box for object 2 "PAScar" (Xmin, Ymin) - (Xmax, Ymax) : (32, 251) - (188, 319)
Bounding box for object 3 "PAScar" (Xmin, Ymin) - (Xmax, Ymax) : (472, 245) - (574, 290)
```

This is the relevant part of my code:

```
if($file =~ /\.xml$/i)
    {   $i += 1;
        open (MYFILE, $file); 
        $newlines = "";
        my $objnum;
        $objnum = 0;
        while (my $row = <MYFILE>) 
        {
            my $line;
            $line = "";
            if($row =~ m/\d+(?:\s+\d+){3}$/)
            {
                $objnum=$objnum+1;
                if($row =~ /CDATA/)
                {
                    my($prefix, $suff, $nums) = split(/\[/, $row);
                    $line = $nums
                }
                else
                {
                    $line = $row;
                }
                my ($x1, $y1, $x2, $y2) = split(" ",$line);
                $newlines = $newlines.'\n'.'Bounding box for object '.$objnum.' "PAScar" (Xmin, Ymin) - (Xmax, Ymax) : ('.$x1.', '.$y1.') - ('.$x2.', '.$y2.')';
            }
        }
        close MYFILE;
        my $tempfile;
        my $newfile;
        $tempfile  = "D:/PATH/temp.txt";
        open (my $tmp, '>>:crlf', $tempfile) or die "** can't  open temp file:( **";
        print $tmp $newlines;
        close $tmp;
        copy $tempfile, $file;
        unlink  $tempfile;
```

The problem is that my converted file looks like this:

```
\nBounding box for object 1 "PAScar" (Xmin, Ymin) - (Xmax, Ymax) : (335, 248) - (450, 305)\nBounding box for object 2 "PAScar" (Xmin, Ymin) - (Xmax, Ymax) : (32, 251) - (188, 319)\nBounding box for object 3 "PAScar" (Xmin, Ymin) - (Xmax, Ymax) : (472, 245) - (574, 290)
```

Why is there no newline?
I'm running on windows. I know that this isn't a Notepad++ problem. It shows up like this on Notepad and Wordpad too. I tried using `\r\n` but that didn't make new lines either.

Then, rather than simply printing `$newlines` into the new file, I tried doing this: `@lines = split("\n", $newlines);` and then running a `foreach $line (@lines)` loop where I opened the file anew in each iteration:

```
foreach $line (@lines)
        {   open ($tmp, '>>', $tempfile) or die "** can't  open temp file:( **";
            print $tmp $line;
        }
```

but I get the same result, except this time without the `\n`s, but everything on the same line.

What to do?

Comment: What about enclosing the \n in **DOUBLE** quotes, like in : $newlines = $newlines."\n".'Bounding ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the line:

```
$newlines = $newlines.'\n'.'Bounding box for object '.$objnum.' "PAScar" (Xmin, Ymin) - (Xmax, Ymax) : ('.$x1.', '.$y1.') - ('.$x2.', '.$y2.')';
```

to:

```
$newlines = $newlines."\n".'Bounding box for object '.$objnum.' "PAScar" (Xmin, Ymin) - (Xmax, Ymax) : ('.$x1.', '.$y1.') - ('.$x2.', '.$y2.')';
```

I.e. you need to but \n in double quotes, "\n", not single quotes, '\n', to make it a linefeed.